# Unity, JSON-сериализация не работает

Tags: json, unity3d, сериализация

Пытаюсь сделать JSON-сериализацию окна редактора в Unity. Но получаю в JSON'е какую-то ерунду, а именно: `{"m_MinSize":{"x":100.0,"y":100.0},"m_MaxSize":{"x":4000.0,"y":4000.0},"m_TitleContent":{"m_Text":"VisualScripting","m_Image":{"instanceID":0},"m_Tooltip":""},"m_Pos":{"serializedVersion":"2","x":920.0,"y":104.80000305175781,"width":144.0,"height":454.0},"m_PersistentViewDataDictionary":{"instanceID":0}}` Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
    public class SimpleVisualScripting : EditorWindow
{


    private GUIStyle nodeStyle;
    private GUIStyle selectedNodeStyle;
    private GUIStyle inPointStyle;
    private GUIStyle outPointStyle;

    private ConnectionPoint selectedInPoint;
    private ConnectionPoint selectedOutPoint;

    private Vector2 offset;
    private Vector2 drag;

    [MenuItem("Window/Visual Scripting")]
    public static void OpenWindow()
    {
        SimpleVisualScripting window = GetWindow<SimpleVisualScripting>();
        window.titleContent = new GUIContent("VisualScripting");
    }

protected void OnDisable()
    {
        // We get the Json data
        var data = JsonUtility.ToJson(this, false);
        Debug.Log(data); // выводится {"m_MinSize":{"x":100.0,"y":100.0},"m_MaxSize":{"x":4000.0,"y":4000.0},"m_TitleContent":{"m_Text":"VisualScripting","m_Image":{"instanceID":0},"m_Tooltip":""},"m_Pos":{"serializedVersion":"2","x":920.0,"y":104.80000305175781,"width":144.0,"height":454.0},"m_PersistentViewDataDictionary":{"instanceID":0}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, а что не так? что вы ожидаете там увидеть? Вы как раз и получаете сериализуемые данные окна редактора

Comment: Хм, я в этом вопросе новичок, не судите строго...  Я думал увидеть переменные nodeStyle, selectedNodeStyle и т.д.

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить состояние окна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сериализация может видеть только переменные с атрибутом [[SerializeField]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html), либо с публичным модификатором доступа. В вашем случае, чтобы в Json попали и ваши поля они должны выглядеть так:

```
public GUIStyle nodeStyle;
public GUIStyle selectedNodeStyle;
public GUIStyle inPointStyle;
public GUIStyle outPointStyle;
```

или так:

```
[SerializeField]
private GUIStyle nodeStyle;

[SerializeField]
private GUIStyle selectedNodeStyle;

[SerializeField]
private GUIStyle inPointStyle;

[SerializeField]
private GUIStyle outPointStyle;
```

Comment: @AlexHena, пожалуйста, отметьте данный ответ, как верный

Comment: Я отметил. К сожалению, это не будет видно, т. к. у меня не хватает репутации. UPD: нет, можно)